# Bs4 encode Issue - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to work with the website of Central Bank of Brazil.

My thing is getting the data from the notification section when is it related to the "swap" (central bank selling US$ in the local market to control the depreciation of the national money).

I've been having a lot of trouble dealing with the API and encoding. 
This is the part of the site where we can find all the reports: http://www.bcb.gov.br/pre/normativos/busca/buscaNormativo.asp?tema=&startRow=0&refinadorTipo=&refinadorRevogado=&tipo=P&tipoDocumento=0&numero=&conteudo=&dataInicioBusca=13%2F6%2F2018&dataFimBusca=16%2F6%2F2018

When I try to get the html from the main page I got this:

> Divulga as condi\u00e7\u00f5es de oferta p\u00fablica para a realiza\u00e7\u00e3o de opera\u00e7\u00f5es de swap

but it should be:

> Divulga as condições de oferta pública para a realização de operações de swap.

I've tried this fallowing code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'http://www.bcb.gov.br/pre/normativos/busca/buscaSharePoint.asp?conteudo=swap&startRow=0'

data = requests.get(url)
bsObj = bs(data.content, 'lxml')
bsObj.find("div") #returned the example, with the wrong encode
```

## #

```
bsObj = bs(data.content, 'lxml', from_encoding='latin-1')
bsObj.find("div") #the same

bsObj = bs(data.content, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
bsObj.find("div") #the same
```

Does anyone understand what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `ç` is U+00e7, and `õ` is U+00F5, and so on. These are just two different representations of the same string. So, while I'm just taking a guess at your problem given incomplete information, I think it's an educated guess…

If you `print` the string, you will see the human-readable version, with `condições` and so on (unless your Python and console aren't configured to talk to each other properly—but if you're using Python 3.6 or later and a reasonable modern version of Linux, macOS, or Windows, this is unlikely to be a problem).

But if you just evaluate the string at the interactive interpreter, you get the programmer-friendly representation, rather than the human-friendly one.

For example:

```
>>> s = 'Divulga as condições de oferta pública para a realização de operações de swap.'
>>> print(s)
Divulga as condições de oferta pública para a realização de operações de swap.
>>> s
'Divulga as condi\u00e7\u00f5es de oferta p\u00fablica para a realiza\u00e7\u00e3o de opera\u00e7\u00f5es de swap'
```

The latter is nice because you can copy and paste it into your source code as a string literal, and because it'll work even on a badly-configured terminal, but it's not so nice for reading.

The technical difference is that `print` calls [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), while evaluating a string at the interactive interpreter without `print` calls [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

---

Meanwhile: most websites specify their encoding (in at least one of three different ways…), in which case `requests` can automatically decode things correctly if you use `text` instead of `content`:

```
bsObj = bs(data.text, 'lxml')
```

The only reason to do anything other than this is if the website is broken and confuses `requests`.

If you just use `data.content`, BeautifulSoup uses a library called `unicodedammit` to heuristically try to guess the right encoding.

If you use `data.content` and `from_encoding`, you have to know the right encoding so you can pass it in. This is useful as a last resort, but shouldn't be the first thing you turn to.

I suspect `from_encoding=Latin-1` and `from_encoding=UTF-8` don't actually do the same thing. They certainly *shouldn't*. More likely, the former gave you a different, incorrect encoding, but you just didn't notice it was different. Maybe something like this:

```
'Divulga as condi\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00b5es de oferta p\u00c3\u00bablica para a realiza\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00a3o de opera\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00b5es de swap.'
```

That may not look much different if you don't know the 100000-character Unicode table by heart, in hex, but if you `print` it, you can see that it's quite different:

```
Divulga as condiÃ§Ãµes de oferta pÃºblica para a realizaÃ§Ã£o de operaÃ§Ãµes de swap.
```

Comment: Thanks, 
But I didn't understand one part. When I search for bsObj.find("div"), it returns the bs obj with the wrong encode. But when I print it, I returns the same. I've seem this answer at a different post, but I coudn't understand

Comment: For me, the result with the .content and .text was the same. Did you get the text without this encode problem?